# PhoneGap stuck in (webView:identiferForInitialRequest: fromDataSource) kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an iOS/phonegap project that I have inherited requires connecting via websockets.  The application seems to work most of the time.

Sometimes, after connection, the following message appears in the debug console.

```
2014-12-01 15:11:23.167 xxx[4156:1044391] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-12-01 15:11:33.169 xxx[4156:1044391] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

At this point, the entire application freezes.  It appears as if the main run loop is waiting for a response from one of the many calls between JS and the native layer.  It never resolves and prints the error every 10 seconds.

I think this may be an issue with a bug in a JS callback, or a failure to return a proper result from a PhoneGap call.  The problem is that there are a good dozen asyncronous PhoneGap calls happening on connect.

I'm really looking for help to determine if there is:
1.  Some way I can safely recover the webview OR
2.  Track down which of the PhoneGap calls is actually causing the problem

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like the problem was that a runaway phonegap call was causing the JS interpreter in the native layer to take too long.

I ended up logging every call to phonegap (around 30) and identified the runaway call.